# Htaccess redirection 301 folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to do a redirect with htaccess file of my old links

```
www.domain.com/220262/page.html to www.domain.com/video/220262/page.html
```

thank you

Comment: RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/page\.html$ video/$1/page.html [QSA,L,R=301] no work :/

Comment: RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/video/$1/$2.html [QSA,L,R=301] is work !

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/page.html /video/$1/page.html [R=301,L]
```